# Installed 6.x ESXi on Dell R710 from bootable USB

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, dell-poweredge, dell

I have a bootable USB plugged into the internal drive for ESXi, and when looking at the harddrive space, it only show the 32GBs on the usb. The question is, how do I use local server resources such as cpu, ram, and more importantly hdd space?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What are you trying to do ?

Answer (score 3):

without knowing your configuration will be difficult to say but you can discard a hardware issue trying the Dell customised image that contains all the necessary drivers.

https://www.dell.com/support/article/fr/fr/frdhs1/sln288152/how-to-download-the-dell-customized-esxi-embedded-iso-image?lang=en

Answer (score 0):

It's normal for ESXi to be installed on a USB drive, as ESXi needs quite few resources. If you then want to provision space for virtual machines, log into the Web GUI, and create a datastore on the hard drives in the server. This of course requires you to configure the RAID controller properly on the server, for example creating a RAID5 array from your drives.

Comment: Stuggi, I am still really new at building Dell servers and virtualization. I am still stumped at how to configure the RAID controller. Any documentation? On boot the only options I have on Bios 6.6  are F2 - System Setup, F10 - System Services, F11 - BIOS Boot Manager and F12 - PXE Boot. I can not seem to find the section to configure the RAID controller.

Comment: Go for the setup or system services, then you'll find the raid controller settings there if I remember correctly. You can also configure it via iDRAC if I remember correctly.